# In QTest Pulse Test Management tool, unable to link Test Scenarios to the Requirements

Tags: java, node.js, qtest

We get to set some rules, triggers, actions and constants to perform linking of requirements, linking of scenarios, update cucumber json results etc which will ultimately be reflected in Qtest Manager. This in turn is linked to Jira. SO I get to see all the linking and execution statuses on Jira as well. But I am getting below error while executing the rules in QTest Pulse. What does this mean?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUErY.png)

VMError: Failed to load '@qasymphony/pulse-sdk': Unknown type. at _require (/tmp/tmp-8224DLoF0tvd3tni/node_modules/vm2/lib/sandbox.js:324:10) at eval (eval at (/tmp/tmp-8224DLoF0tvd3tni/vm.js:7:3), :1:22) at Object. (/tmp/tmp-8224DLoF0tvd3tni/vm.js:7:3) at NodeVM.run (/tmp/tmp-8224DLoF0tvd3tni/node_modules/vm2/lib/main.js:449:23) at [stdin]:52:34 at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:20) at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:306:38) at Object. ([stdin]-wrapper:9:26) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30) at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:80:25) { name: 'VMError', code: 'ELOADFAIL' } " result: null

Comment: Really nobody in the world to address this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use qTest pulse?

I would suggest starting up the automation host on the machine you want to execute the tests or adding the qTest plugin to Jenkins and link it to qTest Manager to update your results.

I would suggest contacting tricentis support as they would be more helpful.